# What is the product of reaction between haloalkane and ammonia at different stoichiometries?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the difference in products when:

1. a haloalkane reacts with **excess** of ammonia
2. **excess** of the haloalkane reacts with ammonia?

I am sure with the 1st reaction, the mechanism will be nucleophilic substitution and the organic product will be a primary amine but what about the second?

Comment: I suppose you know what are the alternatives of "primary" in "primary amine"?

Answer (score 2):

As per your guess an excess of ammonia when reacted with a haloalkane produces a primary amine via nucleophilic substitution.

$$\ce{R-X + NH3 -> R-NH2 + HX}$$

But when the haloalkane is in excess it subsequently reacts with the primary amine to form secondary and tertiary amines and eventually gives a quaternary ammonium salt.

$$\ce{4R-X + NH3 -> R4N+ + 4HX}$$

These quaternary ammonium salts give α-β alkenes on heating. This type of elimination is known as Hoffman elimination<sup>[[1]](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/32549)</sup>.

> Elimination reactions of 4º-ammonium salts are termed **Hofmann eliminations**. Since the counter anion in most 4º-ammonium salts is
> halide, this is often replaced by the more basic hydroxide ion through
> reaction with silver hydroxide (or silver oxide). The resulting
> hydroxide salt must then be heated (100 - 200 ºC) to effect the
> E2-like elimination of a 3º-amine.
> Example #1 below shows a typical
> Hofmann elimination. Obviously, for an elimination to occur one of the
> alkyl substituents on nitrogen must have one or more beta-hydrogens,
> as noted earlier in examining elimination reactions of alkyl halides.
> [image: Hoffman elimination]

---

**Reference:**

<sup>[(1)](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/32549) Quaternary Ammonium Salts: Hofmann Elimination  https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/32549 (accessed Jun 4, 2021).</sup>